# Почему не работает код с библиотекой anychart?

Tags: javascript

Написал криптографик японскими свечами. Он прекрасно работает [дока на свечи](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Japanese_Candlestick_Chart)

```
async function requestAndTreatment() {
    const response = await fetch(requestURL);
    const res = await response.json();
    let arrr = res.data;
    let arrrReversed = arrr.slice().reverse();

    let time = res.timestamp; //Получаем дату с апишки
    let date = new Date(time);
    console.log(date);
    //заполняет массив информацией
    const point = arrrReversed[offset++];
    datatt.addData([[time, point.open, point.high, point.low, point.close]]);
  }

  let datatt = anychart.data.table(0);

  anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // create a chart
    chart = anychart.stock();

    mapping = datatt.mapAs({ open: 1, high: 2, low: 3, close: 4 });
    // create a japanese candlestick series and set the data
    var series = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping);

    // set container id
    chart.container("containertt");

    // initiate drawing the chart
    chart.draw();

    setInterval(requestAndTreatment, 5000);
  });
```

Попробовал написать для AnyStock OHLC, но у меня нарисовались только две оси, а сами "палочки" не рисуются, почему?  [Дока на OHLC](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/OHLC_Chart)

```
async function requestAndTreatment() {
      const response = await fetch(requestURL);
      const res = await response.json();
      let arrr = res.data;
      let arrrReversed = arrr.slice().reverse();
  
      let time = res.timestamp; //Получаем дату с апишки
      let date = new Date(time);
      console.log(date);
      //заполняет массив информацией
      const point = arrrReversed[offset++];
      datatt.addData([[time, point.open, point.high, point.low, point.close]]);
    }
  
    let datatt = anychart.data.table(0);
  
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
      // create a chart
      chart = anychart.ohlc();

      mapping = datatt.mapAs({ open: 1, high: 2, low: 3, close: 4 });

      // create an OHLC series and set the data
      var series = chart.ohlc(datatt);

      // set the container id
      chart.container("containertt");

      // initiate drawing the chart
      chart.draw();
  
      setInterval(requestAndTreatment, 1000);
```

Использую последнюю версию 8.11.0

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ссылку на библиотеку с документацией и версию, которая у вас.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, добавил